# What actually causes the spinning blue circle in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I thought it was supposed to be when the system is busy, but that's not what I'm seeing.

I have an application which (*almost) always shows the blue spinning wheel when the cursor is over the GUI. But everything seems to function correctly (the GUI is responsive, and other threads seem to be progressing just fine) and looking at CPU use, nothing seems obviously stalled.

So what is the actually state of affairs that triggers the displau of the spinning blue circle?

And does anybody have any suggestions as to how I can find out where the problem is in my code?

- the "almost" is because confusingly, just now when I was looking to see if visual studio's cpu profiling could give me any clues and changing settings I ran it and didn't get the blue circle... but then ran it again with no changes and the blue circle was back.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the cursor in register class

Comment: Just a spinning blue circle or an arrow with a spinning blue circle?

Answer (score 4):

The spinning circle is the busy cursor. Applications can set or unset it for whatever reason they want. In fact, the busy cursor indicates simply that some work is in progress, it doesn't necessarily mean that the application has frozen (although frozen apps do show a busy cursor, too).

This is how you set it:

```
SetCursor(hHourglass);
DoBusyThing();
SetCursor(hRegular);
```

See this answer for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3178525/492336

By the way, the spinning circle in Win7 is actually the hourglass cursor from WinXP and older versions. It's exactly the same cursor, they just changed how it looks.